# If a and b are relatively prime, they must be the first row of an invertible 2x2 matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let *a, b* be non-zero integers. Prove that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime if and only if they are the first row of a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$: that is, there is a matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$

in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.

This is seems so simple, but I've been stuck on it for quite some time now.

It seems to make sense when I look at, as the determinant will need to be 1, since the $\mathrm{gcd}(a, b)$ is obviously 1. And furthermore, since $\mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = 1$ we know there exists a pair of integers, $i, j$, such that $ai + bj = 1$. So $i$ must equal $d$ and $j$ must equal $-c$?

I feel like I'm on the right track, I'm just not certain how to finish it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done (almost) everything already! The matrix you're after is $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-j&i\end{pmatrix}$, which, as you've shown, has determinant one.

I guess the fact that you're missing is this:

$$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)= \{M \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)\cap M_2(\mathbb Z): \det(M)=\pm 1\}.$$

The proof is simple: $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $\pm1$ if and only if
$$M^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(M)}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$has integer coefficients.

Comment: The problem I have stumbled upon, is what if the b and c entries are switched? a and b are still relatively prime and the determinant is still ad-bc? I must be missing something here?

Comment: There is no requirement that the matrix be unique. In fact there will be infinitely many matrices with $a,b$ as their first row. Does that address the issue?

Comment: Not quite, I guess what I'm saying is, what if a and b were the first column instead? To me it looks like this would still work, but we are proving they must be the first row.

Comment: Ah I see. I think you've misunderstood the statement of the problem. It's saying: two integers are relatively prime if and only if there exists a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ with them as the first row. That doesn't mean that there can't be some other matrix with them as the first column.

Comment: Well, that would have saved me a lot of time, and even more pain. But I guess I understand it now! I probably still would have troubles connecting the dots even if I knew that, so thank you for your help, kind sir.

Comment: sorry to follow up on this now. I conjure that we can generalize this to n coprime integers but couldn't come up with a proof.

Comment: thx! what about one direction. If the gcd(a, b, .... n) =1, then they form the first row of a matrix in the group?

Comment: @gerrard if by coprime you mean have no common factor (as opposed to pairwise coprime), then that's true. Just take $u, v$ such that $au+bv = 1$. Use that to form a $2\times 2$ matrix with first row $a, b$. Then put $1$'s on the diagonal.

Comment: yes.  can we prove the case where we have more than two integers?